# Disable some programs from sudo

Tags: linux, sudo

I have a group of trusted developers which I have given sudo permissions on a server but I want to be able to exclude some programs to be run with sudo. For example I would like to disable command `su` from being run with sudo, but to let them run it as their user.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Note that while it's possible, it's completely useless. If you forbid `sudo su`, it still allows `sudo env su`, `sudo sh -c su`, `sudo /totally/not/su` where `/totally/not/su` is a symlink to `/bin/su`, `sudo ~/bin/ls` where `~/bin/ls` is a shell script that runs `su`, `sudo bash`, `sudo zsh`, `sudo python`, `sudo vi` followed by `:shell`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude command with sudoers. Eg:

```
 Cmnd_Alias  DEV_EXCEPTIONS=/bin/su, /usr/bin/vi
 %devgrp    ALL = ALL, !DEV_EXCEPTIONS
```

Results in

```
 User XYZ may run the following commands on this host:
 (root) ALL, (root) !/bin/su, !/usr/bin/vi
```

The user will still be able to run the su command

Answer (score 1):

You cannot¹ do this, **not safely**.

While `sudo` does have a configuration syntax for this, it will not accomplish what you hope. Once you allow root access to a system no amount of blacklisting specific actions will ever lock it down again. The Linux filesystem and process permission model just simply does not allow for it.

Gilles' [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223851/disable-some-programs-from-sudo?rq=1#comment380826_223851) starts to hint at why:

> Note that while it's possible, it's completely useless. If you forbid `sudo su`, it still allows `sudo env su`, `sudo sh -c su`, `sudo /totally/not/su` where `/totally/not/su` is a symlink to `/bin/su`, `sudo ~/bin/ls` where `~/bin/ls` is a shell script that runs `su`, `sudo bash`, `sudo zsh`, `sudo python`, `sudo vi` followed by `:shell`, ...

But that hardly scratches the surface of possibilities.

Don't blacklist, **whitelist**.

Blacklisting actions you don't want to happen *will* be a loosing game. With a blacklisting approach at best you can catch absent minded mistakes and signal politely to a user to remind them you wanted something done another way, you absolutely cannot force them not to do the thing.

If you want a restricted system your only prayer is whitelisting very specific kinds of actions. The actions you can whitelist without opening a system to full root access are executables in a fixed location that do fixed tasks without processing user controllable input. Put the other way you cannot allow

- Write access to any file marked as executable or setuid or otherwise parsed and acted on by root.

  Unexpectedly this can include configuration files for many programs. Even seemingly innocuous `*.ini`, `*.yaml`, or `*.conf` based formats often have options that cause programs to run other processes based on a configuration value. A quick look through by `/etc` folder and I see very few configuration files that I wouldn't be able to exploit for a full root privilege escalation off the top of my head if write access to the config was the only thing I started with.
- Run any process that spawns other process based on user input.

  Look out particularly for granting access to scripts that are controllable by environment variables, process user input, etc. Not much is safe actually.

In short, don't give `sudo` access of any kind unless you ⓐ understand you are giving full control over everything of everybody's or ⓑ thoroughly understand the implications of the carefully controlled single action you are whitelisting.

¹ <sub>I realize this contradicts [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223855/1925) [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223856/1925) but after seeing this question liked elsewhere as a "solution" I think it bears noting in an answer so that it gets read by question visitors. Gilles' [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223851/disable-some-programs-from-sudo?rq=1#comment380826_223851) isn't being taken seriously enough.</sub>

Comment: `But that hardly scratches the surface of possibilities.`  Great understatement!

Answer (score 0):

See my [Detailed Solution Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215684/is-granting-unattended-upgrade-command-to-non-sudo-users-safe/219100#219100). Your solution will be much the same. What you'll want to do differently is use multiple `Cmnd_Alias`'s to make debugging, and adding new commands easier.  You can use these multiple alias strings, in conjunction with the Negate Operator, as DarkHeart pointed out in his answer.